# Logistic regression: grouped and ungrouped variables (using R)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, logistic

I'm reading A. Agresti (2007), *[An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471226181)*, 2nd. edition, and am not sure if I understand this paragraph (p.106, 4.2.1) correctly (although it should be easy):

> In Table 3.1 on snoring and heart disease in the previous chapter, 254
>   subjects reported snoring every night, of whom 30 had heart disease.
>   If the data file has grouped binary data, a line in the data file
>   reports these data as 30 cases of heart disease out of a sample size
>   of 254. If the data file has ungrouped binary data, each line in the
>   data file refers to a separate subject, so 30 lines contain a 1 for
>   heart disease and 224 lines contain a 0 for heart disease. The ML
>   estimates and SE values are the same for either type of data file.

Transforming a set of ungrouped data (1 dependent, 1 independent) would take more then "a line" to include all the information!?

In the following example a (unrealistic!) simple data set is created and a logistic regression model is build.

How would grouped data actually look like (variable tab?)? How could the same model be build using grouped data?

```
> dat = data.frame(y=c(0,1,0,1,0), x=c(1,1,0,0,0))
> dat
  y x
1 0 1
2 1 1
3 0 0
4 1 0
5 0 0
> tab=table(dat)
> tab
   x
y   0 1
  0 2 1
  1 1 1
> mod1=glm(y~x, data=dat, family=binomial())
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Table 3.1 is reproduced below:

[image]

Agresti considered the following numerical scores for snoring level: {0,2,4,5}.

There are two ways to fit a GLM with R: either your outcome is provided as a vector of 0/1 or a factor with two levels, with the predictors on the rhs of your formula; or you can give a matrix with two columns of counts for success/failure as the lhs of the formula. The latter corresponds to what Agresti call 'grouped' data. A third method, which also applies to grouped settings, would be to use the `weights=` argument to indicate how many positive *and* negative outcomes were observed for each category of the classification table.

Data in matrix view would read:

```
snoring <- matrix(c(24,35,21,30,1355,603,192,224), nc=2)
```

From this, we can generate a `data.frame` in long format (2484 rows = `sum(snoring)` observations) as follows:

```
snoring.df <- data.frame(snoring=gl(4, 1, labels=c("Never", "Occasional",
                                                   "Nearly every night", 
                                                   "Every night")),
                         disease=gl(2, 4, labels=c("Yes", "No")),
                         counts=as.vector(snoring))
snoring.df <- snoring.df[rep(seq_len(nrow(snoring.df)), snoring.df$counts), 1:2]
```

And the following two models will yield identical results:

```
levels(snoring.df$snoring) <- c(0, 2, 4, 5)
y <- abs(as.numeric(snoring.df$disease)-2)
x <- as.numeric(as.character(snoring.df$snoring))
fit.glm1 <- glm(y ~ x, family=binomial)

fit.glm2 <- glm(snoring ~ c(0, 2, 4, 5), family=binomial)
```

That is, $\text{logit}[\hat\pi(x)]=-3.87+0.40x$, using Agresti's notation.

The second notation is frequently used on aggregated table with an instruction like `cbind(a, b)`, where `a` and `b` are columns of counts for a binary event (see e.g., [Generalized Linear Models](http://data.princeton.edu/R/glms.html)). It looks like it would also work when using table instead of matrix (as in your example), e.g.

```
glm(as.table(snoring) ~ c(0, 2, 4, 5), family=binomial)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! A perfect answer!

I have one simple addition:
Instead of as.table(snoring) I would suggest table(x,y, dnn=c('snoring','disease')) as an equivalent of my example, because the transformation of ungrouped to grouped data was also of interest.

Comment: @FloE You're right. You will still need to construct your rhs *ad hoc*. For example, something like `tab <- table(x,y, dnn=c('snoring','disease')); glm(tab ~ as.numeric(rownames(tab)), family=binomial)` would work (minus sign reversal for the coefficients because "Yes" is coded 0 instead of 1).